# How to redirect from parent page to its child page?

Tags: custom-post-types

I am new to WordPress development. After develops a simple from the scratch everything works fine. Now I want to create a custom page template to show case all e-books with a just thumbnail of the cover and the price. To brief description, I want to redirect to a particular page. It's all like from the Blog list to particular blog page.

I created the custom page with specific style. Now my problem is I don't know how to redirect to its particular page for purchase.

How do I do that? Any instruction will be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url of the single page using this function in wordpress [get_permalink($postid)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean with "particular page",

You don't need to redirect to the custom page. WordPress will handle it if the page followers the naming guidelines to ensure it's detection.

Then the [templates hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) will make the magic.

If it's a one page layout, the filter [`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) and a special logic on the callback function will redirect to your template.
If it's a template page, you need to select it in the post edit screen.

Hope it helps